# How to get to Hive table from R

Tags: r, hive, odbc

I'm trying to read tables from Hive in R but it doesn't work

Connection exists but i can't get to any table:

```
dbListTables(con)
d <- dbReadTable(con, "my table")
```

I get the list of tables but when I want to read specific table "my table" I got error:

> Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) :
>   nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1344: 42S02: [Hortonworks][SQLEngine] (31740)
>   Table or view not found:

Comment: What is more i tried to get to table by  this:                                                             
`tbl(con, in_schema("my schema", "my table"))
typeof(Customers)  ` and it worked but in result  have list and i dont know how to get to variables from table

Comment: What is interesting i have few schemas, private and common. When i copied table to common schema it worked. How to deal with it in my schema???